# In Kentico 10 wildcard URLs combined with language prefixes don't work

Tags: kentico

In Kentico 10 I enabled "Use language prefix for URLs" in Settings -> URLs and SEO. All my urls are being redirected correctly except for the one that uses wildcard aliases.

```
/page -> /en-US/page
/cart -> /en-US/cart
/test/abc/123 -> /en-US/test
```

the /test url is defined with a page alias like follows

```
/test/{partid}/{desc}
```

It always strips off the wildcard parts.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it behaves like this (might be a bug). But if you switch the alias to "Route" and disable redirection then it stops redirecting.

[image: Url Alias]

You can then access the routing data through macros like this:
`{%CurrentRouteData["partid"]#%}` and `{%CurrentRouteData["desc"]#%}`.